# Adding tooltip to UIbutton

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, tooltip

Hey, am trying to figure out how to set up a button so that when the user clicks it a tooltip appears above it giving a brief description, similar to what happens when you click a pin in Google maps.

Does anyone have any ideas how to do this?

Thank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey, managed to get there in the end. What I wanted was a `UIMenuItem` and then just position it above my button by setting its frame